# how to hide pager in ionic slider if image is unavailable

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-slide-box

How to hide the image scroll if the image is empty?
I have four images, where 3rd and 4th images will not be mandatory should be  shown up, if the image name is `noimg.jpg` ,  How to achieve this?

below code , hide the image but still the auto scroll goes and [image]

```
  <ion-slide-box auto-play='true' does-continue='true' slide-intervel='30000'>
   <ion-slide> 
    <img style="width:150px;height:150px;alignment-adjust: middle;"  src="http://www.xx.com/uploads/icons/{{y.menu_icon}}"/>
   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide> 
      <img style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-left: 40px;alignment-adjust: middle;" src="http://www.xx.com/uploads/icons/{{y.menu_icon2}}"/>
   </ion-slide> 
   <ion-slide ng-show="y.menu_icon3 != 'noimg.jpg'"> 
      <img style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-left: 40px;alignment-adjust: middle;" src="http://www.xx.com/uploads/icons/{{y.menu_icon3}}"/>
   </ion-slide> 
   <ion-slide ng-show="y.menu_icon4 != 'noimg.jpg'"> 
      <img style="width:150px;height:150px;margin-left: 40px;alignment-adjust: middle;" src="http://www.xx.com/uploads/icons/{{y.menu_icon4}}"/>
   </ion-slide-box>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show-pager="false"` attribute

OR

with css you can do `.slider-pager { display:none; }` conditionally if there is no data for slider.

Regards.